# What is the maximum speed an AMX 40 can achieve over flat terrain?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I've rebought my AMX-40 lately after reading a guide which tries to fix the issues with the tank (it's speed mostly) and I noticed that sometimes I can reach 26-7kmh on flat pavement surfaces (no hard terrain, no slopes).

I was wondering what is the maximum speed I can achieve over flat non-resistant terrain? (using skills, food, gasolIne, etc). Is there a tool which can be used for such calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute highest top speed for the AMX-40 is 56kmh. However, this can only be achieved with endgame upgrades, which are very hard to get, and it would be a waste using them on a low tier tank.

There is a tool, called [tanks.gg](https://tanks.gg/list), that can be used to calculate such things. [Here is a link to tanks.gg that shows how to achieve that 56kmh top speed](https://tanks.gg/tank/amx-40/stats?e=14.18.13&k=1.5.7&c=4.B.8).

Using the tool, you can build your tank as you wish, and it tells you the exact stats. For example, you add the crew-skill Brothers in Arms to your crew and tanks.gg calculates what effect that skill will have on the performance of your tank during battle.

[image: Screenshot from tanks.gg]

You can easily use the tool for yourself, it's easy to understand if you have basic knowledge of the game. Just select a tank and then add the modules, crew skills and consumables. The tool will calculate every important statistic for you, even the hidden ones you can not see in the game (f.e. gun-handling).

Comment: @Gnemlock Yes, I will edit my answer and give a direct example to op's question.

Comment: Excellent! I reformatted your answer to bring the answer to the top, to say "this is the answer, this is how I got that answer, this is the tool you can use". This could really help future askers, who just want to know how to work this kind of stuff out. +1 from me.